# pyspark map type contains duplicate keys

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Could someone help me understand why the map type in pyspark could contain duplicate keys?

An example would be:

```
# generate a sample dataframe
# the `field` column is an array of struct with value a and value b
# the goal is to create a map from a -> b 

df = spark.createDataFrame([{
    'field': [Row(a=1, b=2), Row(a=1, b=3)],
}])


# above code would generate a dataframe like this
+----------------+
|           field|
+----------------+
|[[1, 2], [1, 3]]|
+----------------+

# with schema
root
 |-- field: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- a: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- b: long (nullable = true)
```

Then I applied `map_from_entries` on this dataframe, trying to collect unique `a->b` pairs. I was expecting the map to contain unique keys, that is `{1 -> 3}` in this case. However, I'm getting {1 -> 2, 1 -> 3} before collecting. This contradict the common idea of a `map` type.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df.select(F.map_from_entries("field"))

# the result is
+-----------------------+
|map_from_entries(field)|
+-----------------------+
|       [1 -> 2, 1 -> 3]|
+-----------------------+
```

I also tried to apply `F.map_keys()` on this field and got `[1, 1]` as the result. However, when I collect this dataframe, I was able to get the result without duplicate keys:

```
df.select(F.map_from_entries("field")).collect()

# result
[Row(map_from_entries(field)={1: 3})]
```

This is causing some unexpected behavior in my spark job, and I would really appreciate if someone could help me understand why pyspark is behaving in this way. Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: please paste a sample code to create the df with the column  field , it will help us to understand and provide solution in a more structured way . Also if the code is in pyspark , can you try to use the create_map function .

Comment: @AdityaVikramSingh hi aditya, thanks for responding. i've updated the description with code snippet for generating the dataframe.

Answer (score 3):

It goes back to the implementation of maps in Scala:
[https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#toMap[T,U]:scala.collection.Map[T,U]](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.12.2/scala/collection/immutable/List.html#toMap%5BT,U%5D:scala.collection.Map%5BT,U%5D)

> Duplicate keys will be overwritten by later keys: if this is an unordered collection, which key is in the resulting map is undefined

Therefore the map 1->3 overwrites 1->2. This is the designed behaviour and not a bug.

Comment: thanks for the reference. i understand why 1->3 is kept when collecting the result. my question was why both keys are kept before collecting.

Comment: I guess that's a bug in Spark 2.4. In Spark 3.0 I get an error when calling df.select: `Duplicate map key 1 was found, please check the input data. If you want to remove the duplicated keys, you can set spark.sql.mapKeyDedupPolicy to LAST_WIN so that the key inserted at last takes precedence.`

Comment: @mck How do you actually set this value?